# Which payment methods are available in Google Pay

Tags: online-payment, payment

Is it possible to add to my digital wallet in Google Pay payment methods apart from credit/debit cards such as [ideal](https://www.ideal.nl/en/) or [trustly](https://trustly.com/en/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither iDeal nor Trustly are (currently) supported.

See the Google Pay FAQ for supported payment methods here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2651410

Please note that PayPal is supported in Google Pay and through that you should indirectly be able to use  [all methods PayPal supports](https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/what-payment-methods-can-i-use-with-paypal-faq1867), including  your bank account.